# Why does std::basic_string_view have two equality comparison operators?

Tags: c++, c++20

A quote from the standard regarding `std::basic_string_view` equality comparison operators (see http://eel.is/c++draft/string.view#comparison):

> [Example 1: A sample conforming implementation for operator== would be:

```
template<class charT, class traits>
constexpr bool operator==(basic_string_view<charT, traits> lhs,
                        basic_string_view<charT, traits> rhs) noexcept {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
}
template<class charT, class traits>
constexpr bool operator==(basic_string_view<charT, traits> lhs,
                        type_identity_t<basic_string_view<charT, traits>> rhs) noexcept {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
}
```

> — end example]

Won't the second comparison operator be sufficient for all use cases? If the answer is no please provide the example code that will stop working (or will work differently) if the first comparison operator is removed. If the answer is yes then why does the C++ standard explicitly require the first operator to be defined?

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/v3eaSEgJUmBYhFU0 I think the second operator including ```std::type_identity_t``` won't work for this case.

Comment: @frozenca For that case _only_ the second overload works. The first one would fail to deduce the second parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is insufficient reduction as a result of the adoption of `<=>` in [P1614](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1614r2.html). Before that paper, there were three `==`s in the example:

```cpp
template<class charT, class traits>
    constexpr bool operator==(basic_string_view<charT, traits> lhs,
                              basic_string_view<charT, traits> rhs) noexcept {
      return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
    }
  template<class charT, class traits>
    constexpr bool operator==(basic_string_view<charT, traits> lhs,
                              type_identity_t<basic_string_view<charT, traits>> rhs) noexcept {
      return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
    }
 template<class charT, class traits>
   constexpr bool operator==(type_identity_t<basic_string_view<charT, traits>> lhs,
                             basic_string_view<charT, traits> rhs) noexcept {
     return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
   }
```

At the time, we needed three operators. The `type_identity` ones handle stuff like  `sv == literal` and `literal == sv`, and then you need the homogeneous one to disambiguate `sv == sv`.

With the `<=>` adoption (or, more precisely, the `==` changes from [P1185](https://wg21.link/p1185)), `==` becomes symmetric so you don't need both `type_identity` operators to handle `literal == sv`, just the one suffices. I was basically mechanically going through and dropping unnecessary `==` and `!=` overloads, so I removed that second.

But what I did not realize is with the other one gone, we now no longer need the homogeneous comparison to disambiguate from the other two (we don't have other two anymore, just other one) - it's enough to just have the one `type_identity` overload.

You could open an editorial issue to remove the homogeneous one. Or not, it's just an example anyway.

Comment: That unnecessary first comparison operator is present not only in the example but also the mandatory [string.view.synop] section of the standard. If it really is not necessary it must be removed - making library code shorter and rising less questions from users like me. Could you pretty please deal with opening an editorial issue yourself since even if I open it you probably end up being the one fixing the standard text anyway?